# Twilio Error Invalid Package Name When Installing through Composer?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I Want to Install Twilio Using `Composer`. I have Written the `composer init --require=twilio/sdk` in `cmd` and hit `enter` then it gives an error

```
    Package name (<vendor>/<name>) [khaan g/twilio]:
 The package name khaan g/twilio is invalid, it should be lowercase and have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name, matching: [a-z0-9_.-]+/[a-z0-9_.-]+
Package name (<vendor>/<name>) [khaan g/twilio]:
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `khaan g/twilio` shuld be `khaang/twilio` (no spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

composer init initiates an interactive process to create a composer.json for a new project. when you run the command it asks a series of questions. you don't seem to be giving any answers and it looks like the default guesses are not valid.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#init